# How can I copy part of a mongodb document to a document in a different database?

Tags: mongodb

I want to copy a node from a document in database A to an existing document in database B. Also the two databases are actually in different mongodb instances.  I can connect to both instances using robomongo.  I am a real novice when it comes to mongodb.  I am very familiar with T-SQL but have no idea how to do this in mongo.

Comment: You need to write a script in your favourite programming language (JS, python, ruby, etc). Query DB1, extract node, query DB2, add node to document, persist document (or maybe do a partial update on DB2 if it's possible).

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured.  However I am looking for more specific instructions / examples for how to do that for mongodb.